# Git: Update folder (pull or fetch?) keeping local changes (without overwriting)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I would like an easier way to update a folder to the latest changes in the tree, but keep my conflicted versions of any conflicts.

I can already accomplish this using the following three methods.

Method A:

- A1. Stash changes including untracked files
- A2. Pull
- A3. Stash pop
- A4. Examine the stash pop error message to remove untracked files so that stash pop can overwrite
- A5. Stash pop again
- A6-N. Go through each conflict to tell git to use my copy and mark the conflict as resolved

Method B:

- B1. Stash changes without untracked files
- B2. Pull
- B3. Go through pull error log to find out which untracked files will be overwritten to temporarily rename them
- B4. Pull again
- B5-N. Go through each conflict to tell git to use my copy and mark the conflict as resolved
- BN+1-N+X. Go through each file previously temporarily renamed, delete the old file, and rename the temporary file back to the original name

Method C:

- C1. Clone repository into a new folder
- C2. Delete all files and folders
- C3. Copy or move all files and folders from working directory

In terms of time, method C is the fastest.  However, this hardly seems like the proper way to use git.  Please tell me there is one simple command I can run to accomplish this!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this:

```
git pull --rebase --autostash
```

And then just fix conflicts until "git status" looks happy (and your unit tests pass!).

More info here (blog post):  [Too much with git pull --rebase](https://mergebase.com/doing-git-wrong/2018/03/07/fun-with-git-pull-rebase/)

And here's another idea:

*METHOD D*

- Commit everything in your tree as a new commit.
- `git pull --rebase -X theirs`
- `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

The '-X theirs" on the rebase causes it to prefer your versions of any conflicting hunks.  The "theirs / ours" strategies are inverted when rebasing compared to regular merging, hence the need to specify "theirs" despite "ours" being the stuff you want to keep.

Comment: The problem with `--autostash` is exactly that with *Method A*: conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply committing your temp work?

You can then simply do:
`git pull --strategy-option ours`

Comment: My general problem with this idea is that a lot of changes will never be committed because 1) they are temporary changes made so I can test an area of code or 2) they are trial / proof of concept versions of code that will largely be refactored, are nowhere near a finished version, and may never make it depending on how business needs change.

Comment: What's the problem with committing TEMP trials? `git commit -m "Temp trial foo bar"`. Committing is just putting a snapshot in your local db. If anything it just makes sure you're NEVER going to lose. I don't see any cons.

Comment: Because any subsequent push would break the system for other developers on the branch.  Alternatively, if I develop on my own branch, every subsequent merge to a shared branch would need to be examined in excruciating detail.

Comment: I think you're thinking of it wrong. Moving references in git is very very cheap. (It is actually just writing a 160 bit reference on a file). So whatever you want to do, it's easier to do with commits and just knowing well how to move around/amend/etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you.  Regardless of how cheap it is to perform any operation in git, my latest commit would go from nice clean code to messy garbage code.  I don't want to scour through messy garbage code every time I need to merge to the main branch.

Comment: If you want a clean state, you simply discard the latest commit before merging. `git checkout HEAD~`. if you want to have merged code with your garbage you can rebase your garbage on top of the other branch.